# More efficient and general way of getting a random integer from multiple lists of different lengths

Tags: python, random

What I want is to be able to have mutable lists of mutable length and draw a random number from these lists. The trick is that these lists are different sizes so if a list is smaller than the others a number from it should not come up as often as from the other bigger lists.

Here's what I have now:

```
 import random

 a = 1
 b = 11
 c = 111
 d = 1111
 e = 11111
 f = 111111
 g = f - e
 q = (f - e) + (d - c) + (b - a)
 r = ((f - e) / q ) * g
 s = g - ((b - a) / q ) * g

 low = 1
 mid = 1
 high = 1

 i = 1
 while i < 666666:
     x = random.randint(a, b)
     y = random.randint(c, d)
     z = random.randint(e, f)
     v = random.randint(1, g)
     if v < r:
         print(z)
         high += 1
     else:
         if v > s:
             print(x)
             low += 1
         else:
             print(y)
             mid += 1
     i += 1

 print(low, mid, high)



  ...
  72027
  81188
  57 6579 660032
```

It works, but it's very crude and requires me to know which list is the longest, etc. Thanks.

Comment: If you expect us to understand your script, you should use meaningful variable names, not single letters.

Comment: Why don't you just concatenate all the lists and pick a random element from that?

Comment: Where are the lists? Do you mean the ranges?

Comment: @Barmar, will a screenshot help: https://i.imgur.com/4hDqxLV.png

Comment: @Hierarchist Please don’t share information in images when it could also be presented as text.

Comment: @AMC, just trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of all the input lists. Then pick a random number from `0` to the combined length of the lists. Then loop over the incremental lengths of the lists until you get to the one where the index points, and select the element of that list.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l2 = [10, 20, 30]
l3 = [100, 101, 105, 107, 111, 125, 130]
l4 = [200, 202, 204, 300, 303, 306, 400, 404, 408]
list_of_lists = [l1, l2, l3, l4]
index = random.randint(0, sum(len(l) for l in list_of_lists))
listnum = 0
prev_length = 0
running_length = len(list_of_lists[listnum])
while index >= running_length:
    prev_length = running_length
    listnum += 1
    running_length += len(list_of_lists[listnum])
result = list_of_lists[listnum][index - prev_length]
```

Comment: Can we do `random.shuffle(list_of_lists)` and pick 1st element each time??

Comment: No, that won't weight the results by the lengths of the lists.

Comment: I tried running that code and it says "NameError: name 'l1' is not defined". Looks like something is wrong with it.

Comment: Those are just sample names I made up for the input lists.

Answer (score 0):

Just pick from the concatenaded lists, possibly without reinventing the wheel and avoiding indexing:

```
import itertools as it
import random as ra

l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l2 = [10, 20, 30]
l3 = [100, 101, 105, 107, 111, 125, 130]
l4 = [200, 202, 204, 300, 303, 306, 400, 404, 408]

res = ra.choice(list(it.chain(l1, l2, l3, l4)))
print(res)
```

Note: if the number of lists varies, make a list of them and pass it to [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)